# Does $.post execute any javascript

Tags: jquery

Does $.post execute any javascript on the page it is fetching after it is fetched?

If so how can I stop that?

Thanks,

Mat

Comment: What do you mean by this? This is highly dependent on context, but $.post is not responsible for executing any JS the browser is. If you grab a chunk of HTML and insert it into the DOM the browser will execute scripts. Otherwise it won't. Totally dependent on the content/type of the HTTP response that comes back in the body.

Comment: Remove the javascript from the page being fetched? If scripting enters the DOM and would activate on the fetched page's normal load, it will be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unless the content received contains javascript which is then inserted into the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't.... but if you add the markup returned by the ajax request to the dom then any script in that markup gets executed